# Set text box value and submit form when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown timer (in this example 8 hours) and when I press the start button it begins counting down. What I want to do is when the page is left or refreshed I want the countdowns current value to be saved. The only way I can think of doing this is assigning the countdown value in a hidden text box and submitting the form when the page is refreshed.

But I'm not sure if this is possible, I can get the value of the countdown timer but I am unable to assign it to an input box and submit the form when the page is refreshed the script I'm attempting to use is below:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
      $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#task_time", function() {
            var hour = $('.jst-hours').html();
            var min = $('.jst-minutes').html();
            var sec = $('.jst-seconds').html();
            $("#current_task_time").val(hour+min+sec);
            $("#hidden-form").submit();
      });
});
```

The selectors (jst-hours etc.) are the hour minute and seconds and I have assigned each to a variable I have then tried to set the value of the hidden input box current_task_time to those variables and then submitting the form. And I want this all to be executed when the page is refreshed (using `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){`).

I am very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for web storage in JavaScript:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Local storage allows you to save values in the users cache, so if they reload then those values will persist as long as they don't clear their cache.

Session storage allows you to save values in the users cache as long as they have that tab open, so for one session.

Good luck!

Comment: This wouuld mean that for this I would probably want local storage I believe.

Comment: @MikeAbineri Yes, for this purpose I believe that is the one that you are looking for, as it would allow you to continually return back to the page indefinitely.